# How to implement image fit mode change animation in flutter

Tags: flutter

This is how I set up a fullscreen image

```
Image.network(
    "https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2017/02/21/21/13/unicorn-2087450_1280.png",
    fit: BoxFit.contain,
    height: double.infinity,
    width: double.infinity,
  )
```

I want to implement resize animation to switch between image fit `BoxFit.contain` or `BoxFit.cover`(like a lot of video app did)

I am pretty new for the animation behavior, could anyone give a help, thanks.

Comment: I'd recommend giving this [Hero Animations] article a look through as a `Hero` widget will probably be the simplest solution for this.

Comment: Sorry messed up the link to the article. Here you go: [Hero Animations](https://flutter.io/docs/development/ui/animations/hero-animations)

Comment: But doesn't Hero Animation used to animate between two screens, It seems not right to implement a new screen for an Animation, I never implement an app before, that is the common way to implement this kind of behavior?

Comment: yep, hero animation will be fine,  or do you have a video or gif about what you need?

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/0VyBzpL  It is what I want when you watch a stream app, like netflix, there is a fullscreen icon to let you switch fit contain or fitHeight. In my case, each image size(width, height) would probably different, but I still want it is fullscreen, only in different fit

Comment: In my test, Hero Animation only works if the Hero A image is not fullscreen(height, width are not double.infinity). It still changes without animation when both images is fullscreen(height, width are double.infinity)

Comment: After test `RectWeen` and some other animation, I know the main problem is I don't know the image size width and height in a fit mode because I want the image is fullscreen, so its container's size already was equal screen width and height, so there is nothing changed for animation beside for the fit mode. When I try to give an image fixed width, height these animation work.

Comment: @pskink How you get the image size from network? If there is image size then it could calculate the fit container size through `applyBoxFit`, then the animation might work!

Comment: @pskink I saw you use the image is `ui.Image`, How to convert an `Image.network` to `ui.Image`, I couldn't find a way to do it, thanks

Comment: Not yet, but I indeed get the image info(size) through https://gist.github.com/ilake/8dbb811080e8e9a2904ffe09239692d6

Comment: @pskink Your ImageAnimator works great, thanks for your kindly help, I learn a lot, thanks.

Comment: @pskink It is how I use the ImageAnimator https://gist.github.com/ilake/2026af363f81159d85d666ff03e74651, and it is the result https://imgur.com/a/zBgavb1, What problem do you mean?

Comment: OK, it is what it looks like https://imgur.com/o5ghHBJ, ya, it indeed kinda weird.

Comment: https://codeshare.io/244qAL looks better now and the code is much simpler but i am not sure about `BoxFit.scaleDown` case

Comment: https://imgur.com/FzHwBLW is better, but how come my Size instance doesn't have `aspectRatio` function I need to handle it manually `final double inSizeAspectRatio = inSize.width / inSize.height`; My Flutter is 1.0.0 and Dart 2.1.0

Comment: OK I find out I am in stable channel, and `Size.aspectRatio` currently is in master channel.

Comment: i am in [dev](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/wiki/Flutter-build-release-channels#dev) channel - *"The latest fully-tested build. Usually functional, but see Bad Builds for a list of known "bad" dev builds. We continually try to roll master to dev. Doing so involves running many more tests than those that we run during master development, which is why this is not actually the same to master"*

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to switch the fit value then you'll need to create a StatefulWidget and keep the the fit value as a member variable and then call setState() and change the value in there. There won't be animations but you can take care of that using an animated container. So the steps would be:

**Switching fit value**

1. Turn your view widget into a StatefulWidget
2. Store your BoxFit value as a memberVariable. BoxFit _imageFit
3. Change _imageFit inside a setState call.

   ```
   setState(() {_imageFit = BoxFit.fitHeight;});
   ```

**Animating your image size**

1. Wrap your image in a AnimatedContainer() widget and set it's dimensions using local member variables

   ```
   double _animatedContainerHeight = yourStartingValue;
   double _animatedContainerWidth = yourStartingValue;
   ...
   AnimatedContainer(height: _animatedContainerHeight, 
   width: _animatedContainerWidth, child: YourImage);
   ```
2. Supply the AnimatedContainer with the duration and interpolation and then Change the size of it in the setState function mentioned above.

   ```
   setState((){
    ...
     _animatedContainerWidth = newValue;
     // same for height
   });
   ```

Comment: In my case, the fullscreen image, the container width, and height should always equal screen width and height, however, there is no transition when I only change BoxFit value even the image is already the child of AnimatedContainer. And it seems not right to calculate every image's width and height when they are in BoxFit.contain and assign them back to AnimatedContainer and let AnimatedContainer control image size.